# Web Audio API channels aren't down-mixed

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, channel

I have an AAC file with 6 channels. If I open it directly in a browser, I hear all 6 channels down-mixed to play on my stereo speakers. If I play it via the Web Audio API, I only hear the left and right channels.

I'm loading the buffer, creating an AudioBufferSourceNode, assigning the buffer to it, and then connecting to the AudioContext's destination.

From my console:

```
> buffer.numberOfChannels
6
> source.channelCount
2
> source.channelCountMode
"max"
> source.channelInterpretation
"speakers"
> context.destination
AudioDestinationNode {maxChannelCount: 2, channelInterpretation: "speakers", channelCountMode: "explicit", channelCount: 2, numberOfOutputs: 0…}
```

Is this the reason that I'm not hearing the other channels, because `destination.channelCountMode` is `explicit`?

Is there some way to change this or get the AudioContext to use its [down-mixing logic](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#UpMix)?

I've created a [simple jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/y2XHM/4/) showing the setup. If you download the file directly, you'll hear the 6 channels down-mixed into 2, but not if you run it through the Web Audio Context.

Comment: The Web audio API should do what you are looking for. Can you provide a jsfiddle of your code with the sample?

Comment: +1.  Send a file along, I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a jsFiddle.

Comment: @Florestan06 Let me know if that's enough to work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you noticed your JSFiddle works ok in Firefox? Chrome on the other hand does not work as "expected". I am saying expected because as Web Audio is still a draft not all features may be implemented yet by all browsers supporting it (FYI see browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/audio-api)).

I have put an example that should work as you want [here](http://jsfiddle.net/florestan06/Ryjk4/1/). 
As you suspected you need to implement the down mixing logic following the W3C spec you mentioned. This is done through the [createScriptProcessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/AudioContext.createScriptProcessor) method in conjunction to the audioprocess event.

The code as follows (it is not production ready as such but you can take it from here :)):

```
<script src="http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/js/buffer-loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;
var context;
var bufferLoader;

function init() {
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new AudioContext();
bufferLoader = new BufferLoader(
    context,
    [
    'http://labs.bubblefoundry.com/internet-of-cars/corsproxy.php?url=http://labs.bubblefoundry.com/internet-of-cars/sounds/5_1IDENT.m4a'
    ],
    finishedLoading
);
bufferLoader.load();


function finishedLoading(bufferList) {
    var javascriptNode = null;
    var source1 = context.createBufferSource();

    source1.buffer = bufferList[0];
    javascriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 6, 2); // audioContext.createScriptProcessor([bufferSize][, numberOfInputChannels][, numberOfOutputChannels]);
    source1.connect(javascriptNode);
    javascriptNode.connect(context.destination);

    console.log(javascriptNode);

    function onProcess(e) {     
        var in1 = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // Left input
        var in2 = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1); // Right input
        var in3 = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(2); // Center input
        var in4 = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(3); // (??)
        var in5 = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(4); // Left Surround input
        var in6 = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(5); // Right Surround input

        var leftOut = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0); // Left output 
        var rightOut = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(1); // Right output 

        for (var i = 0; i < in1.length; i++) {
            leftOut[i] = in1[i] +  0.7071 *(in3[i] + in5[i]); // W3C formula for Down Mixing
            rightOut[i] = in2[i] + 0.7071 *(in3[i] + in6[i]); // W3C formula for Down Mixing
         }
    }
    source1.start(0);
    javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = onProcess;  
}
}
</script>
```

I have noticed your channel 4 (marked ?? in my comment) seems to be silent. But here my knowledge of surround sound may fall short.

Comment: Ha, of course it didn't even cross my mind that Chrome didn't have down-mixing yet. Thanks for the example!

Comment: PS Channel 4 is probably the subwoofer.

Comment: Web Audio API is very promising indeed - still needs a bit of work. Have fun with it :)